# Introduce time delay before moving flow files to next processor in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

In NiFi, there exist a data flow to consume from *MQTT* (ConsumeMQTT) and publish into *HDFS* path (PutHDFS). I got a requirement to introduce *60 min* delay before pushing the consumed data into HDFS path. Found ControlRate and MergeContent processor to be possible solution but not sure.

> What is the ideal solution to introduce time delay?

**Example:** A flow file consumed at 9:00 AM should be published into HDFS at 10:00 AM

[image]

Comment: why not just to schedule PutHDFS to run every 60 sec?

Comment: @daggett, we have various process group and each process group output is directed to a common PutHDFS processor. So changing the configuration of PutHDFS will impact other flows as well. Hence its not possible in my case

Comment: put some dummy updateattribute before puthdf and specify required schedule for it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use an `ExecuteScript` processor to run a `sleep(60*60*1000)` loop, but this would unnecessarily use system resources.

I would instead introduce a `RouteOnAttribute` processor which has an output relationship of `one_hour_elapsed` going to `PutHDFS`, and `unmatched` looped back to itself. The `RouteOnAttribute` processor should have **Routing Strategy** set to *Route to Property Name* and a dynamic property (click the **+** button on the top right of the Properties tab) named **one_hour_elapsed**. The Expression Language value should be `${now():toNumber():gt(${entryDate:toNumber():plus(3600000)})}`.

This expression:

1. Gets the current time and converts it to milliseconds since the epoch (`now():toNumber()`)
2. Gets the `entryDate` attribute of the flowfile (when it entered NiFi) and converts it to milliseconds and adds one hour (`entryDate:toNumber():plus(3600000)` [`3600000 == 60*60*1000`])
3. Compares the two numbers (`a:gt(${b})`)

If this is not actually the start of your flow, you can use an `UpdateAttribute` processor to insert an arbitrary timestamp at any point of your flow and calculate from there.

I would also recommend setting the **Yield Duration** and **Run Schedule** of the `RouteOnAttribute` processor to be substantially higher than usual, as you do *not* want this processor to run constantly as it will do no work. I'd suggest setting this to 1 or 5 minutes to start, as you are introducing a one hour delay already.

[image: Flow showing timing loop]

Comment: If you want a delay on the flow level (e.g. since a certain timestamp) this is probably the only straightforward way. However, since the new RetryFlowFile processor is introduced, it is likely more elegant for pure delays at a certain point in the flow. -- I see that someone already wrote an answer with this.

Comment: I'm not a fan of busy waiting.

Answer (score 8):

Starting from nifi 1.10 this can be done even easier with the RetryFlowfile processor.
Use penalty duration for setting the delay time:

[image]

Comment: I like this approach. It is much simpler.

Comment: Where is the penalty duration property?

Comment: Not in the "Scheduling" tab, but in the "Settings" tab

Comment: You'd like to configure this processor as "Maximum Retries" set to 1, and Automatically Terminate Relationships: "failure". The expected delayed flowfile will be in the "retries_exceeded" relationship